# singleton instance does not override and empty getter setter

Tags: c#

the Name get only in the Main a value but not in `public plname` but the problem I dont want that people use Main they use `public plname` like below and the override also not works, can someone help me

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : new()
{
    public static readonly T Api = new T();
    protected Singleton() { Console.WriteLine("Inited"); }
}
public class SomeSingleton : Singleton<SomeSingleton>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SomeSingleton() { }
    public virtual string getPluginName() { return Name; }
}
public class plname : SomeSingleton
{
    public plname() { // this not works
        Name = "test";
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Api.Name = "testing"; // this works
        Console.WriteLine(Api.getPluginName());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public override string getPluginName()
    {
        return "this not works"; // this not works
    }
}
```

Edit:
the `Singleton` and `SomeSingleton` class are in a .dll file the `plname` class is not in the dll

I want to use it like this

```
public class plname : SomeSingleton
{
  public plname {
     Name = "test";
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? Please write in detail what the problem is, what the error message is (if you get any) and what you are struggling with.

Comment: I have added how I want it, this not works means that the value of Name is not the string that I wrote

Comment: What do you mean with "is not the string that I wrote"? You assign a value to the property `Name` but don't use it anywhere else. Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: that means If I do this `Name = "test";` in `public plname` and return that with `Api.getPluginName()` the Name value is empty

Comment: `Api.getPluginName()` will return the `Name` property from the object in the static property `Api`. But you have set it to "testing".

Comment: yes I have set it to "testing" that works I wrote it also there but If I remove it the Name property is empty but why because I set it in `public plname` to `"test"`

Comment: Why not use MEF or some other plugin system, rather than writing your own?

Answer (score 1):

Within your `Main` method, which is a method within a type that (indirectly) inherits from `Singleton<SomeSingleton>`, `Api` refers to `Singleton<SomeSingleton>.Api`. This is a *static* member of the type `Singleton<SomeSingleton>`. So it is explicitly *not* a new member of neither `SomeSingleton` nor `plname`.

Since `Api` is now a member of `Singleton<SomeSingleton>` that means that it only gets initialized once. And at that time, it gets the value `new T()` where `T` is `SomeSingleton`.

That means, unless you actively change the instance that exists at `Api`, it will always refer to the same `SomeSingleton` instance, which gets instantiated without any data (and without a name).

That is why you get `null` when you just do `Api.getPluginName()`: Because that static instance of `SomeSingleton` never had a name initialized. And since that instance is explicitly *not* an instance of `plname`, the overridden method of `plname` will also not apply.

As a result, you will just have to live with the fact that inheriting singletons is generally not something that will really work because singleton references to the original type will not be magically updated.

Assuming that you want to write some kind of plugin system, it is probably a better idea to do that without having to rely on singletons at all. Or alternatively, just have a single singleton that allows you to *register* your plugins in some registry.

---

An example for this would be the following:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    string Name { get; }
    void DoStuff();
}

public static class PluginRegistry
{
    private static readonly List<IPlugin> plugins = new List<IPlugin>();
    public static IEnumerable<IPlugin> GetPlugins() => plugins;
    public static void Register(IPlugin plugin) => plugins.Add(plugin);
}

// And then an example plugin implementation
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public string Name => "My fancy plugin";
    public void DoStuff() => Console.WriteLine("My fancy plugin was called!");
}
```

Register your plugin somewhen:

```
PluginRegistry.Register(new MyPlugin());
```

And then you can use the `PluginRegistry` to access your plugins:

```
foreach (var plugin in PluginRegistry.GetPlugins())
    plugin.DoStuff();

// Output:
// My fancy plugin was called!
```

Comment: hey thanxs for your answer can you give me a example how I can do it and yes it is a plugin system

Comment: is there no way to set the `Name ` value because I dont want write my own plugin system this is a api to create a own plugin the methods are DllExported can I contact you and show you the full project?